# How to scroll windows with Imwheel in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scrolling

In Ubuntu 22.04 I am trying to vertically scroll windows faster with the mouse wheel, which is currently impossible in the mouse settings and requires the installation of `imwheel`.

Here is what I did:

```shell
sudo apt install imwheel -y
nano ~/.imwheelrc
```

Pasting in Nano and saving:

> ".*"
> None,       Up,     Up,     18
> None,       Down,   Down,   18

And yet the vertical scrolling remains the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably doesn't work with Wayland. Try to log out, select "Ubuntu on XOrg" as your desktop and log in again.

Comment: @gronostaj I tried but nope, sadly, windows behave the same...